# how to forward docker port 2375 from virtualbox to host os windows 10

Tags: docker, virtualbox, portforwarding

I created a debian vm to have my docker host running on.

**netstat**

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2375          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1260/dockerd

After that I setup port forwarding for port `2375` as described in many online tutorials.

[image]

Next I `curl` in the cmd of my windows 10 host os.

```
C:\Users\me>curl localhost:2375
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

Notice that connecting to the VMs SSH port is working.

```
C:\Users\me>curl localhost:666
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1
Protocol mismatch.
```

Can anybody tell me what am I missing? Do I have to kinda *allow* port `2375` to be called from outside where the SSH port is allowed by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your docker listening IP.

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:2375 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1260/dockerd
```

`127.0.0.1` means it is only listening for connections generated from inside the VM.

You should change your docker daemon to use `0.0.0.0:2375`. Then your port forwarding would work

Comment: will try that - what exactly does 0.0.0.0:2375 stand for? Don't have that much of a network background

Comment: When you use `0.0.0.0` it means listen on available interfaces. So if you VM has multiple ethernet interfaces, then it will be listening on each interface. When your Hosts accesses the VM it is a external traffic. And `127.0.0.1` is local loopback address. Which points to the machine in context

Comment: Ah okay! `10.0.2.15` is the address the vm actually has - so i tried that instread of `0.0.0.0` and it worked, too.

Comment: That is interface that would be bringing in the external traffic, so that's why